Azure pipeline stopped giving installable MAUI app
I have an Azure pipeline which has been building my MAUI app fine but a few weeks ago a problem occured. After the app is built and deployed for user download (in a custom online location, not the Google Play store), I try to install it manually on my few phones and every time it just says "Application cannot be installed", without any specific error details.
Interestingly enough, when I 'run dotnet build MyApp.sln -c Release' on my local machine, in the source folder, it builds the app just fine and I can then install it on all the phones without problems.
I have tried adding a signing step in the Azure pipeline and it seems to be working but the output apk still won't install on phones.
The YAML code I added for signing the app (which didn't help):
- task: AndroidSigning@3
  displayName: 'Signing and aligning APK file(s) **/*.apk'
  inputs:
    apkFiles: '**/*.apk'
    apksign: true
    apksignerKeystoreFile: myappkey.keystore
    apksignerKeystorePassword: mypass
    apksignerKeystoreAlias: myappkey
    apksignerKeyPassword: mypass

Any idea what I might be missing?

Hi @Val, Have you got a chance to test the suggested step below to sign the app during dotnet publish? Hope it works for your as well.

Turns out I was looking for the solution in the wrong place as it wasn't a problem with the YAML config.
I installed the app using android-adb to be able to see the logs and the exact error message. It turned out that I was trying to install a build generated by a different source (Azure instead of local machine) and needed to manually uninstall the old app first for that (Android won't do it automatically).
If I keep installing new versions of the app built on the same machine, I don't get the error anymore.

Thanks for the update and amicable sharing of the solution to keep installing new versions of the app.

Based on my testing with the dotnet publish command for my MAUI application, the .apk file generated during pipeline build can be installed manually, regardless of whether it is signed with the app key. I'm not certain if signing the package was a requirement when you built your app on your local machine. For your reference to build a signed app package in a pipeline, I have included a sample YAML definition below:
parameters:
- name: DotNetVersion
  default: 8.x
- name: ApplicationDisplayVersion
  default: 1.0.0

stages:
- stage: BuildAndroid
  dependsOn: []
  jobs:
  - job: BuildAndroid
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
    steps:
    - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
      inputs:
        secureFile: 'DotNetMauiAppDemo.keystore'
      name: DownloadKeystore
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: .NET Version
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '${{ parameters.DotNetVersion }}'
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Install MAUI
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "Downloaded keystore file is $(DownloadKeystore.secureFilePath)"
          dotnet nuget locals all --clear 
          dotnet workload install maui --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json # --source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet7/nuget/v3/index.json
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build Android App
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '**/*.sln'
        arguments: >
          -f net8.0-android -c Release
          -p:ApplicationDisplayVersion=${{ parameters.ApplicationDisplayVersion }} -p:ApplicationVersion=$(Build.BuildId)
          -p:AndroidKeyStore=true -p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=$(DownloadKeystore.secureFilePath) -p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=DotNetMauiAppDemo
          -p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=$(KeyPWD) -p:AndroidSigningStorePass=$(KeystorePWD)
        zipAfterPublish: false
        modifyOutputPath: false
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/DotNetMauiAppDemo/bin/Release/net8.0-android/'
        Contents: 'publish/**'
        TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    - publish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifact: 'dropAndroid$(Build.BuildId)'
    - powershell: |
        tree $(Agent.WorkFolder) /F /A
      displayName: Check Binaries
      condition: always()

- stage: DeployAndroid
  dependsOn: BuildAndroid
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployAndroid
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
    environment: E-GooglePlay
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: current
            artifact: dropAndroid$(Build.BuildId)
          - powershell: |
              tree $(Agent.WorkFolder) /F /A
            displayName: Check Artifacts
            condition: always()
          - task: GooglePlayRelease@4
            inputs:
              serviceConnection: 'GooglePlaySvcCnn'
              applicationId: 'com.domain.dotnetmauiappdemo'
              action: 'SingleBundle'
              bundleFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/dropAndroid$(Build.BuildId)/publish/*-Signed.aab'
              track: 'internal'
              changesNotSentForReview: true




Sorry, I haven't tested your solution because someone else suggested to me to install the app using adb to be able to see the logs and the exact error message. It turned out the pipeline was not the problem but the fact that I was trying to install a build generated by a different source (Azure instead of local machine) and need to uninstall the old app first for that.

Thanks for your update and let us know this is not a pipeline problem. Good luck with the works to go. Cheers.

@Val, If possible, please brief introduce your solution in the answer, which may help others with similar concerns. Thx.
